# SAS Data Integration Studio: problems with sending mail (log in attach)

Tags: sas

I'm an inexperienced user of SAS Data Integration Studio.

I would like to receive an e-mail information about the job status. Using "Status Handling" and action "Send Email" (from job options) is not satisfying to me. First of all - (propably?) i can't attach log to this e-mail.

In SAS Enterprise Guide I developed and tested code for sending email with log in attach and some useful informations (datetime, list of errors) in mail body:

```
%let mail = "test@test.com";
%let path_error = /home/ ... .log;

filename msg email
 to =           (&maile)
 subject =      "SAS Message Test"
 attach =       "&path_error.";

data _null_;
 dttm = put(datetime(),nldatm.);

 infile "&path_error.";
 input;

 file msg;
 if _n_ = 1 then do;
    put "Date time: " dttm;
    put;
    put "Full log in attach.";
    put "There are some ERRORs and WARNINGs:";
    put;
    end;
 if substr(_infile_,1,5) = "ERROR" then 
    put _infile_;
 if substr(_infile_,1,7) = "WARNING" then 
    put _infile_;
run;
```

This code works fine - I get complete mail with list of errors and warnings. In log I can see:

```
NOTE: 268 records were read from the infile "[...].log"
```

But how to implement this code (especially reading by infile statement) in DIS?

I have modified the job options:

1. Precode - puts the log into an external file; log name contains jobname and datetime:

```
%let path = /home/[...]/log_&etls_jobName._%sysfunc(datetime(), datetime.).log; 
proc printto log="&path.";
run;
```

2. Postcode - I used code from Enterprise Guide:

```
%let address = "test@test.com";
%let message = problems with &etls_jobName;

         filename sendMail email 
                to=         (&address) 
                subject=        "ETL Process problem: &etls_jobName." 
                attach=     "&path."; 

            options nosyntaxcheck;  

         data _null_; 
            dttm = put(datetime(),nldatm.);

                infile "&path.";
                input;

                file sendMail; 
                 if _n_ = 1 then do;
                    put "Date time: " dttm;
                    put;
                    put "Full log in attach.";
                    put "There are some ERRORs and WARNINGs:";
                    put;
                    end;
                 if substr(_infile_,1,5) = "ERROR" then 
                    put _infile_;
                 if substr(_infile_,1,7) = "WARNING" then 
                    put _infile_;
         run;
```

In effect I get e-mail with log in attach, but empty body. In attached log I can see:

```
NOTE: 0 records were read from the infile
```

I've got some questions:

1. Why 0 records???
2. When I delete `input;` statement from Postcode and run job I get e-mail with "Date time / Full log in attach / There are some ERRORs and WARNINGs" in body. Why they are deleted where `input` works in code?
3. E-mail is not sending without `options nosyntaxcheck;` in code. Why?

Thanks for the answers.
Regards,
Michał

Comment: Does the file you are trying to read with the INFILE and INPUT statements exist?  Does it have any lines in it?

Comment: Yes, file exist and Enterprise Guide can read it...

Answer (score 0):

The normal way for a data step to stop is when it reads past the end of the input (either raw data being read or datasets being accessed).

So move your _N_=1 block to BEFORE the INPUT statement.  You might want to change the wording of the message about the errors and warnings. Or wait to write until after you know there are records to be read.

```
%let address = "test@test.com";
%let message = problems with &etls_jobName;

filename sendMail email 
  to=(&address) 
  subject="ETL Process problem: &etls_jobName." 
  attach="&path."
; 

options nosyntaxcheck;  

data _null_; 
  dttm = put(datetime(),nldatm.);

  file sendMail; 
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    put "Date time: " dttm;
    put;
    put "Full log in attach.";
    put "There are some ERRORs and WARNINGs:";
    put;
  end;

  infile "&path.";
  input;
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    put "There are some ERRORs and WARNINGs:";
    put;
  end;
  if substr(_infile_,1,5) = "ERROR" then put _infile_;
  if substr(_infile_,1,7) = "WARNING" then put _infile_;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. But still Data Integration Studio reads 0 records from **any** infile. This code works in Enterprise Guide and records are redaded by infile statement.

Where is the problem source in Data Integration Studio?

Comment: You are either running on a different machine or with a different account that does not have access to that file.  Or you have some previous errors in your code that has caused SAS to set system option OBS to 0 to prevent you from doing more damage.